# Preventing a line break at the end of a sentence

Tags: line-breaking, hyphenation, white-space

If I want to prevent a line break between two words, then I insert a `~` like this:

```
Lorem~impsum.
```

But what if I want to prevent a line break between the end of a sentence and the first word of the new sentence. If I do it like this

```
Lorem ipsum.~Dolor sit amet.
```

then the spacing is not correct after the full stop. I can think of

```
Lorem \mbox{ipsum. Dolor} sit amet.
```

but this would prevent `Dolor` from breaking into two lines if necessary. What other options do I have?

Comment: `zzz.\nolinebreak\space This`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `\nolinebreak` to add a penalty to prevent breaking at that point.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\setlength\xspaceskip{25pt}% for effect

1 Lorem ipsum.~Dolor sit amet.

2 Lorem ipsum. Dolor sit amet.

3 Lorem ipsum.\nolinebreak\space Dolor sit amet.


\vrule\parbox{2.7cm}{%
1 Lorem ipsum.~Dolor sit amet.

2 Lorem ipsum. Dolor sit amet.

3 Lorem ipsum.\nolinebreak\space Dolor sit amet.
}\vrule


\end{document}
```